# Fixed string with spacebars and EOF check

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, char

Okay, here I have this snippet of code:

```
struct Computer
{
    char name[20];
    float hdd;
    int price;
    int ram;
};

struct Computer list[7];
int n = 0;

for(n; n < 7; n++)
{

    printf("\nEnter PC name, 20 characters:");
    /* here should be name entry for list[n].name */
}
```

Many ways just doesn't work. I tried `fgets()`, `getch()`, `scanf()` and plenty other things but it either didn't work, or didn't have enough functional.

`fgets(list[n].name, 20, stdin)` cant recognize EOF in entry, and this is needed.

`list[n].name[counterChar] = getch()` have just some strange behaviour and have many routine with echoing.

`scanf("%c", &list[n].name[counterChar])` makes user press enter after every symbol.

What I need is: name is limited to 20 characters, includes whitespaces, if `EOF`, then break out of loop.

Comment: How exactly would you like to terminate each input for a complete `name` entry? For example, let's say you want to give it the name `"Ha Ha!"`, what would you like to do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
int ret; 
...
{
    ret = scanf(" %19[^\n]", list[n].name);
    if(ret == EOF)
        break;
```

To clarify what this code is doing:

- This reads 19 characters (leaving 1 space for the null terminator). If you read a full 20 into your `name[20]` you'll fill the array and not leave room for [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to append the null terminator (`'\0'`). If you really wanted 20 characters then you need to bump up your arrays to `name[21]`.
- The format string takes advantage of the [negated scanset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and tells `scanf()` to stop at newline characters instead of "all white space" characters. This means it will read spaces, but also other white space characters (such as tabs, line feeds, etc). 
  If this is not what you can adjust the scanset by adding more "stop" characters in there. For example if you wanted it to stop on a newline or a tab you could do: `" %19[^\n\t]"`
- The format string also has a space between the initial `"` and the `%`, this is intentional. It tells `scanf()` to ignore any whitespace left on the `stdin` buffer. Using `scanf()` in a loop will leave the previous newline character (`'\n'`) on the buffer.
- Finally, check the return value of `scanf()` to break from the loop of you got `EOF`. You can see this is what you'll get if an `EOF` is encountered instead of a string from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.

Comment: @ajay - Yes... and? "reads past white space (only stops at newlines)" == "it reads spaces too"

Comment: This actually works, for except, instead of 19 should be 20, and field should be of 21 size, for pure 20 symbols. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You should use maximum field width in the format string of `scanf` to guard against buffer overrun and check the return value of `scanf` for `1` to determine if the call was successful.

```
struct Computer list[7];
int n = 0;
int retval;
char ch;

for(; n < 7; n++) {
    printf("Enter PC name, 20 characters:\n");

    // save one char space for the null byte 
    // appended by scanf at the end
    retval = scanf("%19[^\n]", list[i].name);  
    if(retval == EOF)
        break;

    if(retval == 1) {
        // if the input was longer than 20 chars
        // then discard the extra input if this is
        // what you want so that it doesn't mess with
        // the next scanf call

        if(strlen(list[i].name) == 19) {
             // read and discard extra input 
             // up till and including the newline 
             while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')  
                 ; // the null statement
        }    
    }
}
```